# Magento 2.1.12 - all products not showing up categories and search results frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, product, category, search, bug

Since this weekend one of our Magento stores stopped displaying products on all category pages and the search results page. We have tried everything from reindexing all products, deleting the var folder, redeploy all content, setup upgrade/compile. But nothing seems to solve the problem. The error log returns nothing and the store is in dev mode. I've also checked both the categories and the products but nothing has changed which could have caused this.

Does anyone know the issue or got a solution to the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one of the modules was corrupted along with the outdated encryption file under the framework of the website. Because of this the search index did not work correctly which caused the products to be invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Products missing from category pages often has to do with a problem in the catalog search index. Double-check the search engine in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search. See if changing it and re-indexing has any effect.

Comment: Checked this, catalog search is on mysql and re-indexed but the products are still not showing up.